# Bug in Preview when copying and pasting an image?

Tags: macos, preview

Is Preview.app buggy in OS X 10.10, Yosemite, or is it because of the Nvidia Web Drivers?

I opened an image in Preview, copy the image, created a new file, and pasted it. The color looks more purple?

The blue image in the back is the original and the purple is the new file created copying and pasting the image. Problem is not there if I use Adobe Photoshop. So, I guess it is a Preview bug. Can any one confirm this behaviour?

[image]